# How do I clean up my mac folders?

Tags: cleaning

I have a lot of random files that are left over from like previous plugin installs and app installs with a `.` prefix. How should I go about cleaning these up and knowing what I can delete and what I can't? For example, I installed powerline a while back but then I deleted it. However, I just found the leftover files in my bin directory that were never deleted. For files such as these, how should I figure out what I can delete and what I can't?

Comment: Doesn't macos have some type of program or package manager, or an "uninstall" list to cleanly uninstall things? Like the package managers on Debian (apt/dpkg) or other distros use like pac(kage)man(ager), R(edhat)P(ackage)M(anager)

Comment: I use homebrew but I think there are many times when the files are not cleanly uninstalled and so over the years I have accumulated a lot of junk files. Also sometimes some plugins ask to install using git clone or clone or some other install method and I just copy the command without having the best understanding of where and how it's being installed.

Comment: That's unfortunate, it's about as bad as Windows ;-) I expected they might have taken some package management features when they switched to being more unix / bsd like. Just a guess, but comparing to another clean install might show some differences...